# Magento and Amazon RDS - timeouts

Tags: php, mysql, magento, pdo, rds

I have a Magento CE 1.7 installation on an Amazon EC2 instance with the Magento database on an Amazon RDS Large database instance. Generally things seems to be configured ok.

However, when performing bulk import operations I am hitting some sort of 120 second failure. I kick off the import process and exactly 120 seconds in Chrome tells me:

Error 324 (net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE): The server closed the connection without sending any data

Sure enough the import has failed.

I have tried the often given advice of the php.ini settings:

`memory_limit = 256M`

max_execution_time = 1800

But they don't fix it. I have tuned a number of RDS Parameter Group settings as well:

`innodb_lock_wait_timeout=120`

for example - but again no success.

It is clear that there is some hard-coded 120 second limit somewhere (i've timed it many times!) but i cannot work out what parameter is causing the issue.

I have tried cutting up the import file into small sections and it runs just fine when i do that. So its not input data related either

Any help much appreciated - have pushed 2 days into this issue already :(

TIA!

Comment: Is it behind a load balancer?

Comment: Cool, went ahead and posted an answer then :)  Glad that was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that there's a hard limit for timeouts on ELB load balancers.

Answer (score 1):

as suggested by sarcksoft the issue was to do with load balancer. The ELB drop connections that are idle for 60 seconds. Had to work around by doing batch jobs direct to EIP on separate sub-domain.